# Convert plain text with html tags to html string and render it in Blazor

Tags: blazor, blazor-client-side

Sample:

```
@{
     var s = "<p>Sample text</p>";
 }
```

Expectation:

`Sample text.`

I want it rendered on browser but I couldn't render it. It just outputs the whole value of s as text string. I already try

```
@(new HtmlString(s))
```

encoded it with `HttpUtility.HtmlEncode` and decode it with `HttpUtility.HtmlDecode` but still no use.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You will need

```
<div >@((MarkupString)s)</div>

@code
{
    string s = "<p>Sample text</p>";
}
```

The `<p>` will render inside the `<div>`

Comment: Google couldn't find that `MarkupString` keyword.

Answer (score 2):

Using RenderFragment :

```
@page "/"

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

@StringToHtml("Hello<h1>text</h1>")

@code {

    RenderFragment StringToHtml(string htmlString)
    {
        return new RenderFragment(b => b.AddMarkupContent(0, htmlString));
    }
}
```