# html format in blazorise DataGrid

Tags: html, datagrid, blazor, blazorise

I'm using the Blazorise DataGrid  in my Blazor .NET6 app. In the DataGrid table I want to show html content e.g. a link. So I am providing a string like

```
<a href="address">This is a link</a>
```

to the DataGrid. DataGrid is not converting the string to the actual link but is printing the text.
How can I format the DataGrid content so that it converts the string to a html element?

**Summary:**

I provided a string representing a html element to Blazorise DataGrid and expected that this string is converted but it's not.

Answer (score 1):

> expected that this string is converted but it's not.

You will have to [cast the string to a `MarkupString`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60168291/60761).

Either add a property to your (View)Model or use something like a template column. I don't know the Blazorise Grid.